# Access methods on different types

Tags: java, android, inheritance, methods

I have something like this:

```
Figures fig = new Line();
```

on which Line extends Figure. Figure is an abstract class that only has a method `getType()` that tells me which figure it is by returning a `String`;
I have 3 types, `Rectangle`, `Circle` and `Figure`. All of them extend `Figures`.

Now the real question. I store every single one inside of a `List<Figures>` and I want to get access to some methods on each object like `getStartX()`; and `getStartY()`; and I can't, I only can access the methods that are on `Figures` also.

Comment: Does the methods `getStartX()` and `getStartY()` exists in `Rectangle` and `Circle` classes?

Comment: Yes it does, but I want to access other methods that aren't in common with this 3, like getradius(); that is only inside Circle...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `instanceof` with `if...else` and cast dynamically your object

```
Figure fig = new //Circle()/Triangle()/Rectangle();

if( fig instanceof Circle) {
   ((Circle) fig).getRadius(); //This method is only available in Circle class
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU !!! This does work!!

but with a minor change, I only use 
((Circle) fig).getRadius(); because my abstract class already tells me the type  ^^
Many thanks !!!

Comment: Pleasure is mine, because you seems new on StackOverflow, don't forget to mark your question as solved.

Answer (score 1):

Your abstract class should define the `getStartX` and `getStartY` method. Either abstract if you want `Rectangle`, `Circle` and `Figure` to have a different behaviour and force them to `Override` those methods. Else just put the method in `Figures` it'll be available for use (with the appropriate keyword : `public`/`protected` depending your needs).

If you want to use methods that are specific to a class you'll need to check of which instance it is. Something like

```
for (Figures figure: myList) {
  int x = figure.getStartX(); // Method common and declared in Figures  
  if (figure instanceof Circle) {
    System.out.println("Oh no a Circle!");
    int radius = ((Circle)figure).getRadius();
    ...
  }
}
```

For your Rectangle/Line you can define an interface with your 2 methods:

```
public interface HasEndpoints {
  int getEndX();
  int getEndY();
}

public class Rectangle implements HasEndpoints {
   ...
   public int getEndX() {return endx;}
   ...
}

for (Figures figure: myList) {
  int x = figure.getStartX(); // Method common and declared in Figures  
  if (figure instanceof HasEndpoints) { // Rectangle and Line will go there
    System.out.println("HasEndpoints implementor");
    int endX = ((HasEndpoints)figure).getEndX();
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: But the thing is that I have other 3 methods that i also must have access that aren't in common with all of the classes (Rectangle/Circle/Line)

Comment: like getRadius(on Circle) and getEndX and getEndY( on Line/Rectangle)

Comment: updated answer. You should maybe get an extra common parent for Line and Rectangle, or use an interface like (HasEndPoints) which would define your 2 methods.

Comment: `getStartX()` cannot exists in `Figure`, because a `Circle` is a `Figure`.

Comment: @Ian2thedv I don't get your point. If `getStartX()` is defined in `Figures` and `Circle` at some point extends `Figures` then it's accessible ...

Comment: @MichaelLaffargue that is my point, that it is accessible. A `Circle` has no `startX` or `startY`, a property that belongs to a `Line`, and a `Line` only. It just seems cleaner to me. If you prefer all the methods possible on every type of figure in the parent class, you'll have to throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` in each implementation.

Comment: @Ian2thedv Oh ok, well that's the OP choice. startx on a circle could be the center, or the first point at 0 degree on the circle

Comment: @MichaelLaffargue No, the `x` and `y` coordinates will be used to determine the length of the line, thus it has no meaning in the `Circle` implementation. To calculate the circumference of the circle, only the radius is required.

Comment: @Ian2thedv Unless you read mind, you can't imagine what the OP will do with his methods. I'm not discussing geometry here but class inheritance.

Comment: @MichaelLaffargue true, we don't know what OP will do. What is the point of inheritance if the methods inherited from parent classes is not applicable to the child classes? IMO, it should be **generic**. And BTW, we are essentially discussing logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can always cast the Figure to Line, but not the best choice. Depending on the problem, you can apply [Visitor Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/visitor) or add those methods to Figure, even when the Circle doesn't have a starting and ending point.

For example

```
public abstract class Figure{
    public abstract void visit(FigureVisitor visitor);
}

public class Line extends Figure{
    public void visit(FigureVisitor visitor){
        visitor.visitLine(this);
    }
}

public interface FigureVisitor{
    public void visitLine(Line figure);
    public void visitCircle(Circle figure);
}

public class StartingPointsVisitor implements FigureVisitor{
    private Double startX;
    private Double startY;
    private Double endX;
    private Double endY;

    public void visitLine(Line figure){
        this.startX = figure.getStartX(); //No cast needed
        ...
    }
    public void visitCircle(Circle figure){
        //Stub-method
    }

    //Getters to read the results
}
```

Is a more complex solution, but as i said, it depends on the problem, and most of the complex remains in the Visitor

Answer (score -1):

Either `getStartX()` and `getStartY()` should be declared in `Figure` class or you need to cast the object to `Line` class:

```
Figure figure = figures.get(0);
if ("line".equals(figure.getType())) {
   Line line = (Line)figure;
}
```

Another option is to use reflection. But you still need to be sure, that the requested method can be called.

Comment: If `Figure fig = new Circle()`, what would you expect the output of `getStartX()` to be?

Comment: @Ian2thedv Please read my answer: **either** the method is declared in *Figure* class (what returns the *Circle*, implementator must know, not me - it can throw UnsupportedOperationException eg.) **or** use casting.

Comment: you did not mention anything regarding UnsupportedOperationException in your answer.

Comment: @Ian2thedv because it doesn't make any difference